# I want to apply dynamic formula using query string for Map

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I want to add calculation on Map dynamically using query string, as shown below. I will define variable:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> data= new Map();
data["qty"] = 12;
data["price"] = 18;
```

I want to write just like a string query like below

```
string string = "Content data["amount"] = data["qty"]*data["price"]";
```

I want to execute this string and it return Map values which I will add to data map code here, it is possible in flutter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package
[Math_expressions](https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions)

And solve math expressions using string like the following

```
Parser p = Parser();
Expression exp = p.parse("(x^2 + cos(y)) / 3");
```